# Remove points from geom_sf and plot borders

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, ggplotly

I have a map of municipalities and states and I would like to plot the borders of each state based on the geometry of these municipalities. I am using `geobr` library.

I tried to group the municipalities by state and then get the geometry but it returned many points as can be seen below. I just want the borders (the thick lines around each state, not the points). Is there a way to get it? My code for this is as follows:

[image: Map with points and borders]

Code:

```r
ggplot(df_mun) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Mortalidade), size=0.5, color = "gray50") +
  geom_sf(color = 'black', fill = NA, linewidth = 0.75,
          data = . %>% group_by(name_state) %>% summarise())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example that would generate those dots, starting from library loading. Right now it looks like some small sections are cut out from shapes and those holes are now rendered as "dots" .

Comment: Yes, after some hours, I managed to solve this problem using another function that gave me the geometry of the states I wanted. The points are from the geometry of each municipality, they cannot be converted by simply grouping the variables. Thanks for the answer!